# Is there a current source for the LGEO parts library?

Tags: ldraw, part-database

I'm working on a povray render of a model. I've seen the LGEO (not a typo) part library referenced [in various places](https://wiki.ldraw.org/index.php?title=User:Owen_Burgoyne/POV-Ray_Tutorial#Setting_up_the_LGEO_library), but I haven't been able to find a working download link.

Is there a current source for an updated version of this part library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this Eurobricks thread is helpful: https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/108739-new-parts-for-lgeo-library/

It seems that the lgeo library itself is no longer maintained but this person maintains his own version. The download links are on the first page...

Comment: The library you linked to does not include the original LGEO parts by Lutz Uhlmann, nor the updated parts by Owen Burgoyne.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in your "various places" link, the LDraw.org web site maintains an [All-In-One-Installer (AIOI)](http://www.ldraw.org/article/104.html) which contains and installs LGEO and is updated in January every year so I assume they use the latest version of LGEO.

BTW, I found an LGEO quirk when launching POV-Ray from within [LPub3D](https://sites.google.com/site/workingwithlpub/lpub3d) which I use for generating building instructions.  I kept the screenshot below highlighting how you have to tell LPub3D that LGEO is not available, even though the AIOI installed it:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I was aware of the AIOI, but I don't use Windows, so it's not super helpful. In addition, the LGEO link on the AIOI page 404s, so it wasn't clear if this is updated or not.

Comment: Sadly the AIOI download doesn't allow easy extraction of it's contents. You'd need to install it on a Windows instance and then grab the LGEO stuff. However I think Michael's link to the forum is your best bet for up to date parts.

Answer (score 1):

This is now available on [Github](https://github.com/jncraton/lgeo).

I was able to find a working download of just the original LGEO library on [Eurobricks](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/153002-rendering-parts-with-cli/) thanks to some help from the other answerers. I trimmed that down a bit, as that download required integrating some other files in order to work properly. This repo should now work perfectly on its own, but it only includes parts up through 2008 that were created by Lars Uhlmann.

If you are looking for a more complete and cutting edge set of elements, [Darats' version](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/108739-new-parts-for-lgeo-library/) (from the accepted answer) seems to be the most current and high quality.

Answer (score 1):

This wiki page describes how to get all the LGEO parts.

https://wiki.ldraw.org/wiki/LGEO